# grab all divs which does not have a class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab the `div` elements that do not have a specific class, called `active`.

So the code is:

```
 $(currentContainerDiv).addClass('active');
```

Now, the `currentContainerDiv` also has a class `slidingDiv` and now I want to grab all other other
`div`s with the class of `slidingDiv` which don't have `active` attached.

How to achieve this?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
   $('.slidingDiv').not(currentContainerDiv).removeClass('bottomed');
```

Comment: I think you should use this selector:http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: For questions about selecting/traversing elements with JavaScript, and therefore for jQuery also, it's almost always best to post the (relevant) HTML; that way the question is useful to others in future, *and* we can perhaps simplify things for you, or correct your approach (and show why your own approach doesn't, couldn't or wouldn't work).

Comment: I read more than twice.. But i swear i didn't understand anything..

Answer (score 2):

TRy this:

```
$('.slidingDiv:not(.active)').removeClass('bottomed');
```

As you have stated "currentContainerDiv" also have class="slidingDiv". So no need to add filter for this.

Comment: "Now, the currentContainerDiv also has a class slidingDiv and now I want to grab all other other divs with the class of slidingDiv which don't have active attached". Nowhere mentioned about descendant divs. :)

Comment: sorry misunderstood the question.. +1